# Curve not shrink-wrapping to some parts of mesh

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I have a path curve that I want to shrink-wrap to a backpack mesh. The curve does not wrap to the side of the mesh, and ends up looking like this.

[image: Curve not wrapping to side of mesh.]

When I scale the curve so that it will be longer, it looks like this:

[image: Curve not wrapping to side of mesh]

The backpack has no modifiers, and the face orientations are all correct. Subdividing the backpack does not help. I've also tried different curves, like the bezier curve and nurbs curve, but I get the same results.

Why is this happening, and is there a way to fix this, or some workaround to the problem?

The settings for the shrink-wrap modifier looks like this:
[image: ShrinkWrap modifier]

And the settings on the curve are this:
[image: Curve settings]

Comment: Curve resolution?

Comment: Curve resolution is at 12.

Comment: Or "nearest surface point"? have you tried to project instead? Or share your file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Doing project seems to get the curve on the backpack, but the lines going inside the backpack at certain points.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need the curve?

Comment: I'm trying to get a zipper on the backpack, which is a straight string of cylinders, with every other cylinder having a slight offset. I was looking for ways to get it on the backpack, and found out about the curve modifier. So right now, I'm trying to get the curve on the backpack so I can use the curve modifier to get the zipper on the backpack, although if there any better ways to do this, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Shrinkwrap should work, so there is something particular somewhere. Consider sharing your blend file please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: this is the blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dsQvpl1S" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dsQvpl1S/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase the resolution (preview and render maybe, and keep the shrinkwrap to "project" as it is in your shared file):

[image]